# The movement's ideas are not merely absurd; they are __________ dangerous

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which option fits best in the following question?

> The movement's ideas are not merely absurd; they are __________ dangerous.
>
> a. formally
>   b. perfectly
>   c. absolutely
>   d. positively

Some of the options can have more than one meaning, so I list the most possible meanings below:

[**formally**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/formally):  Officially (= in an [official](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/official) way)
[**perfectly**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/perfectly):   In a manner or way that could not be better  (also: used for emphasis, especially in order to assert something that has been challenged or doubted)
[**absolutely**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absolutely):  totally (also: used to emphasize a strong or exaggerated statement)
[**positively**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/positively): with certainty (also: used to emphasize that something is the case, even though it may seem surprising)

The first option, *formally*, is out of picture because the official opinion doesn't necessarily have any relevance to the nature of the movement's ideas. We have to decide between the remaining three options.

There are two sentences:

> 1 The movement's ideas are not merely absurd;
>   2 they are __________ dangerous.

In the speaker's mind it's not enough to say that the movements ideas are *merely absurd*. Something stronger is needed. So they continue: *they are dangerous*, and for emphasis, they add an emphasizing adverb too: *they are .... dangerous*. You can see from the Oxford Dictionary definitions that all the options b, c, and d can be used for emphasis.

My question is: which emphasis fits the context of this question the best?

Comment: For me, option 4 seems like the best choice, but I'm not a native speaker..

Comment: @CopperKettle I found it unfitting because the word dangerous connotes a negative perception which is contrary to  what the word positively does.I can be wrong though

Comment: This is the catch. The word **positively** here means not "in a positive way" but rather "really". These ideas are really dangerous.

Comment: @CopperKettle ok I see but does it fit this sentence also?

Comment: To my taste, the word no. 4 not only fits the sentence, it is positively the best you can choose from the options on offer.

Comment: @CopperKettle Native speaker here - I agree with you, "positively" fits the best out of these.

Comment: I am positively happy that my choice is the same as a native speaker's! P.S. "word no. 4", without "the", of course.

Comment: absolutely, positively...

Comment: In the expression _X is positively Y_, what we mean is that X would get a positive (above-0) score on a scale that measures the attribute Y. So the sentence above would mean that the movement's ideas are not **just** absurd (and thus score 0 for danger); but that they would _actually register a reading_ on a danger scale (which implies a greater-than-0 score for danger). In this sentence, it's a way of insisting on the danger posed by the movement.

Comment: I'm a native speaker (American English) and I choose *positively*.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker I pick "outright", which isn't an option but it is the idiomatic standard word for this phrase.

Comment: @Catija That's the word that sprang to my BrE mind as well.

Comment: @Catija yeah outright would fit just fine for me too (BrE native)

Comment: Too bad it's multiple choice. I would have recommended _downright_.

Comment: @J.R. Would you please explain how _positively_ differs from _downright_ in this context? [I'm told](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/24938?m=28442759#28442759) they work  similarly here.

Comment: @Færd - The two words mean the same, but _positively dangerous_ seems to have the overtones of an oxymoron, which I'd probably try to avoid. There's nothing wrong with it, though – just a personal preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinctions in this question are subtle:

**"Formally"**, as you say, does not fit and is out of the picture.

**"Perfectly"** is an intensifier that compares to potential; if something is "perfectly dangerous", it cannot be any more dangerous than it currently is.

**"Absolutely"** is an intensifier that emphasizes lack of uncertainty; if something is "absolutely dangerous", there is no doubt about its danger.

**"Positively"** is an intensifier that can compare to an earlier qualification; if something is "positively dangerous", then in being dangerous it goes beyond what was said about it before.  Or, as another example, in the exchange

> Q: Are you hungry?
>   A: I'm positively famished.

the response means the same as "I'm famished", but emphasizes that "famished" is more than just "hungry".

You write

> In the speaker's mind it's not enough to say that the movement's ideas are *merely absurd*.

This is the key insight; the speaker is not emphasizing that the danger is maximal, nor that the danger is certain, but that the danger puts the ideas past mere absurdity.
Thus, the correct answer is **"positively"**.

Answer (score 10):

I suspect this is a case where the common English usage seems very odd to a non-native speaker, and I'm afraid I can't offer a good explanation as to WHY it works the way it does, but:

the only form of the above I would expect to hear is 4,

**The movement's ideas are not merely absurd; they are positively dangerous**

In this case, positively doesn't mean good as it usually does, instead it means something more like Actively. 1, 2 or 3 would sound odd to me as a native speaker.

Comment: +1 for "the only form of the above...."  Positively means certainly - as in _"I am positive that your dog is the one who bit me yesterday."_

Answer (score 0):

Taking by basis the word in the first sentence, **absurd**, I would say that the author of the sentence wanted to emphasize the insanity of the ideas. **Positively** gives us the sense of certainty, but **absolutely** gives us the exaggerated meaning, which is fit for this case.